# Recursively set PHP array key/value pairs with dot notation

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I'm working in a Laravel 10.x project using PHP 8.1. I have a model called `BuyerTierOption` which is given to a function called `setOptions` as an array. I need to loop over each option, and select the `name` field and if it contains a dot, to check whether the array exists, if not, create, and the create the key/value pairs within. If it does exist, to simply set the value.

This needs to happen down to any depth.

Here's my attempt:

```php
/**
 * The overrides that we must set on the cloned model
 */
public array $options = [
    'http' => [
        'method' => null,
        'url' => null,
        'timeout' => 60,
        'connect_timeout' => null,
        'options' => null,
        'headers' => null,
        'as_form' => null,
        'retries' => [
            'attempts' => null,
            'backoff' => 100
        ],
        'authentication' => [
            'is_required' => null,
            'username' => null,
            'password' > null
        ],
        'query' => [
            'with_params' => null,
            'params' => null
        ],
    ]
];

/**
 * Set the options for the tier
 */
public function setOptions(array $options = []): void
{
    foreach ($options as $option) {
        if (! str_contains($option['name'], '.')) {
            $this->options[$option['name']] = $option['value'];
            continue;
        }

        $nameParts = explode('.', $option['name']);
        $value = $option['value'];

        foreach ($nameParts as $part) {
            if (!isset($this->options[$part])) {
                $this->options[$part] = [];
            }

            $this->options = $this->options[$part];
        }

        Log::debug('set options', [
            'options' => $this->options
        ]);

        // Set the value only if it's in the provided nested keys
        // if (in_array(implode('.', $nameParts), $this->options)) {
        //     $this->options = $value;
        // }
    }
}
```

You see from my attempt, that I need to override segments of my `$options` array, whilst keeping any default values that aren't specified in my buyer tier options, shown here:

```
{
   "options":[
      {
         "id":2,
         "buyer_tier_id":1,
         "name":"http.method",
         "value":"post",
         "description":null,
         "cast":"string",
         "is_enabled":true,
         "created_at":"2023-09-28T18:25:32.000000Z",
         "updated_at":"2023-09-28T18:25:32.000000Z",
         "is_deleting":false
      },
      {
         "id":1,
         "buyer_tier_id":1,
         "name":"http.url",
         "value":"https://example.com/",
         "description":null,
         "cast":"string",
         "is_enabled":true,
         "created_at":"2023-09-28T18:25:18.000000Z",
         "updated_at":"2023-09-28T18:25:18.000000Z",
         "is_deleting":false
      }
   ]
}
```

The expected result in the end here is that all of my options in `$options` remain unchanged, and my URL and method are set.

I could have a buyer tier option name like `http.retries.attempts` where I'd need to set this too.

If the key doesn't exist, it should create it. What am I missing?

Comment: I don't what you're missing, but I don't see any descent recursion anywhere, which you obviously need, and `$this->options = $this->options[$part];` will certainly ruin your day.

Answer (score 0):

The problem:

- Available configuration array within an object that needs to be populated (in code as `$this->settings`)
- Request data that should be parsed within the configuration (in code as `$options`)

```php
foreach ($options as $option) {
    if (empty($option['name'])) {
        continue;
    }

    \Illuminate\Support\Arr::set($this->settings, $option['name'], $option['value']);
}
```

The mentioned solution uses `Arr` class because the author mentions using Laravel, which provides the Arr class.

The Arr class is able to handle dot-containing keys and behaves just like the author expects.

Comment: fyi, the provided code is not meant to be copy-pasted. One should modify it to his/her needs and apply validation if needed (the question contained 'if it contains a dot' which in this case is ignored and the value is modified even if the value of name does contain no dot)